# How to completely change the list of jetpack's pagination library in android in single click or so?

Tags: android, pagination, android-jetpack, android-pagedlistview

How to change data or completely change the list of pagination in android. I am using android jetpacks pagination library. I also have search and sorting feature.
I am not able to understand where do I change or put new data or list so that the current list disappears and the new list comes up. Should I make new data source for this? or am I supposed to make new data source new data source factory and new pagedList and then submit this list using adapter.submitlist() to the same adapter
? Please help, I am new to using this pagination library.

Answer (score 0):

There's a duplicate question where i give answer for your question.

[How to send search suggestions dynamically to data source and get updated pagelist in Android jetpack paging library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54457490/how-to-send-search-suggestions-dynamically-to-data-source-and-get-updated-pageli)